# If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty finite subsets of a group $G$, prove that $G=AB$ or $|A|+|B|\leq G.$

Tags: group-theory

For the following question: (from A first course in Group theory by Bijan Davvaz)

> If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty finite subsets of a group $G$, prove that $G=AB$ or $|A|+|B|\leq G$, with $AB=\{ab|a\in A, b\in B\}$

To solve it, either assume if $G\neq AB$ then $|A|+|B|\leq |G|.$ or to assume if $|A|+|B|>|G|.$ then $G=AB$. By using the second strategy,  I know that $AB\subset G$, so if for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $ab\in G$.  Then there exist some $g_i\in G$ such that $ab=g_i.$ $G$ being a group, so the inverse of both $a, b$ exists. Hence $a^{-1}g_i=b$ and $g_ib^{-1}=a$.  Now $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|>G,$ $|B|>|G| - |A| \geq |A|>|A\cap B|,$ (not sure if it is $\geq$ or $>$ for $|G| - |A| \geq |A|$) $A\subset AB$ and $B\subset AB.$  I want to show that $G\subset AB$, so for any $g\in G$, I would like to have $g=ab\in AB.$  But I only have $a=b^{-1}g_i$ $b=a^{-1}g_i$, also, I don't know whether they are in $|A\cap B|$ or does that fact doesn't matter?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As a second potential problem with your posting, it seems that you are assuming that $A$ and $B$ are **subsets** of $G$, rather than **subgroups** of $G$.  This means (for example) that if the set $A$ contains the element $a$, that $A$ **might not** contain the element $(a)^{-1}.$

Comment: @user2661923 if I have a conclusion of $A$ or $B$, then this is equivalent to not $A$ implies $B$.   Isn't that equivalent to what I am trying to prove in my question?

Comment: Yes, after re-reading your posting, I agree that your approach is valid.  So, I have deleted my first comment, but I have left in my 2nd comment.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you for pointing that out.  I appreciate it. :)

Comment: See the answer of Damian Pavlyshyn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can proceed according to the first strategy:

Suppose that $G \neq AB$, so let $g \in G \setminus AB$ and denote $g B^{-1} = \{gb^{-1} : b \in B\}$.
Now, since $G$ is a group, the map $b \mapsto gb^{-1}$ is a bijection and so  $|gB^{-1}| = |B|$.

Moreover, $A$ and $g B^{-1}$ are disjoint, since if they had an element $h$ in common, we would have $h = a = gb^{-1}$ for some $a \in A, b \in B$, from which $g = ab$.

Therefore, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
|A| + |B|
= |A| + |g B^{-1}|
= |A \cup g B^{-1}|
\leq |G|.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1: Nice analysis.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn this question has been asked on here. From the various answers, I thought they were using the second strategy but there were somethings i still did not get.  Thank you for making it more clear for me.